# Film about pieces of the sun tracking people thermally and incinerate them

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie I want to find is about pieces of the sun that come down to Earth and they sense heat, like the pieces see thermally, and if a human touches them they get instantly incinerated. It’s been a while, like 8 years, since I’ve seen it. I just want to re-watch it.

Comment: We've had this one before, I think. Let me check.

Comment: Dang it... I even wrote an answer, although the Querent rejected it.

Comment: I want to say it was actually a TV episode. Also, originally a short story involving glad balls on a beach after a lightning strike that are actually seeking each other and killing more incidentally.

Comment: FuzzyBoots: That was Dune Roller by Julian May; it became an episode of "Tales of Tomorrow" But I don't know if the asker is thinking of that. This was in black and white, rather old television.

Comment: FuzzyBoots: I don’t actually know if its a movie or tv show but I remember a scene whear a police officer or like someone in an outfit of a police officer is at a party and when he sees it the music stops and he goes to touch it with his night stick ( i think thats what its called) and when he comes in contact withit he instantly turns into dust

Answer (score 5):

I’m pretty certain you’re thinking of *[The Darkest Hour](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1093357/)*.

Not pieces of the sun but some kind of alien race invading earth.

> Young entrepreneurs Sean (Emile Hirsch) and Ben (Max Minghella) meet stranded travelers Natalie (Olivia Thirlby) and Anne (Rachael Taylor) at a hot Moscow nightclub. Their whole world changes in an instant when an alien attack devastates the city and everything goes dark. Joined by a Swedish businessman (Joel Kinnaman), the youths emerge from hiding days later and must somehow fight back against a nearly invisible enemy that could find and disintegrate them at any moment.
>   <sub>[Google reviews](https://g.co/kgs/yucCMk)</sub>

[image: Cover of the film]

In the trailer, you can see the cop touching the light with the nightstick and turning to dust, as OP said (it’s like 40 seconds in):