# Old book or story about alien stones which glow and merge together

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

From what I remember it is an old book. It's about a guy who lives near woods and is a fisherman. He finds some alien stones that glow and I think burn a hole through his desk drawer. They get larger and merge together. I think aliens come.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [thse guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the most important - how old is "old" ? 50s, 90s, three years ago? "Old" depends a lot on who's asking :)

Comment: This sounds a bit like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193328/short-story-involving-pieces-of-orange-glass-that-seek-out-each-other-and-defend, but not all the details match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, this is [Dune Roller by Julian May](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56099), which was also the answer to [Short story involving pieces of orange glass that seek out each other and defend themselves with heat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193328/short-story-involving-pieces-of-orange-glass-that-seek-out-each-other-and-defend).

The scene you remember with the desk is:

> An odor of burned wood hit his nostrils. He exclaimed shortly under his breath and shone the light down near the sill of the outside door. There was a round black hole in the door, smoking and glowing faintly around the edges.
> He raced back into the workroom and pulled out the drawer that had held the grapefruit-sized drop. It was empty, and a hole gaped in the bottom of it. The hard wood, was still burning slowly.

Comment: @ReneeBarrett: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: You beautiful people thanks so much!!! I read this story in a book given to me by my dad from the 1970s and I think I was about 7-10 years old ish when I read it. I don't remember reading in a sci paperback book. So I think it was a readers digest style book. Thanks so much for soothing this long-held nostalgic thorn! I'm off to read it again now!!

Comment: And now I found thanks to the links the books it was published in. Pretty sure I read it in  Stories for Tomorrow: An Anthology of Modern Science Fiction. I thought it was from the '70s because it was my dad's stuff but it must have been his when he was a teenager.